# Compute nearest points to other points using GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, distance, network

I have a layer of address points and a layer of polling stations. My task is to determine the three closest polling stations to each address on the street network.

I think that the answer is in v.distance, but I am stuck trying to use this tool. I have merged my two point layers, each having a "type" field (either 'address' or 'voting'). It seems that the tool wants the From WHERE condition to be

type=address

...and the To WHERE condition to be

type=voting

I have used v.net.maintenance to make a network of the streets with the merged points as the input point vector map. However, the resulting layer only has attributes of the street network, such as COST. If I input this layer to v.distance as

input=street_network_with_merged_points

...I can use the COST field, but there is no type field for from_where or to_where.

I've seen several postings about using this tool, but no answers.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider to use [v.net.path](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.net.path.html) - finds shortest path on vector network or [v.net.alloc](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.net.alloc.html) - allocates subnets for nearest centers. See also the list of available [vector network algorithms](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/topic_network.html). The [v.distance](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.distance.html) command will find the shortest direct distance but you likely want to follow the network in order to obtain more realistic distances.

Comment: v.net.path shows the shortest path from one node to any number of other nodes, but **through** those other nodes. In this case, the second shortest path to a polling station might be **on the other side** of the shortest path to a polling station. I don't think v.net.path can do that. v.net.alloc will allocate lines to a given polling station, but will not tell me which three polling stations are closest to a given address points. Thanks for the suggestions, though.